# Parse app not playing sound with push notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that uses Parse.com for push notifications. These are triggered with Cloud Code, but those notifications, while firing, are coming in silent, no sound, no vibration nothing.  What is going wrong with it?

```
pushQuery.equalTo('channels', newUserId);
                      if (anonymous2 == "false") {
                      Parse.Push.send({
where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
data: {
alert: firstName2 + " " + lastName2 + " " + "just added a prayer request."
}
}, {
success: function() {
    // Push was successful
},
error: function(error) {
    throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
}
});
                      }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just your iOS's settings that are silencing the notification ... did you check it?

Comment: check that your device settings , it is not related to Parse

Comment: Figured out the issue, for it to play sound, you actually have to set the sound in the data structure of the cloud code, so it technically was related to Parse and not the device settings.  Just had to add `sound: "default.caf"` to the data